# Error with Android Studio Generate JavaDoc

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

I am using Android Studio and attempted to generate JavaDoc for my project via **Tools ==> Generate JavaDoc**.

In the dialog, I configured it with the following:

- Whole Project
- Other command line arguments: -bootclasspath "C:\android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar"

However, after executing it, I am seeing the follow error message at the end:

> javadoc: error -
>   com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   java.lang.FunctionalInterface not found 1 error

How can I resolve this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation type `java.lang.FunctionalInterface` only exists since Java 8, and as such it is not part of the Android runtime you specified in the boot class path.

You could fix the problem by adding the JDK's runtime jar (rt.jar) to the boot class path, but that would only solve the Javadoc generation issue, and not further problems that will arise from using constructs such as FunctionalInterface, which are not part of the Android platform.

A better/safer option would be to run Android Studio with Java 7 instead of Java 8.

Comment: Thank you @Lolo ! Java 7 fixed it.

Comment: How were you able to fix it. I am facing the problem but with so many imports and package not found errors. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78119162/unable-to-generate-android-javadoc-documentation-in-latest-android-studio-giraff