# Unable to generate Android Javadoc documentation in Latest Android Studio Giraffe

Tags: java, android, javadoc

I have tried every single solution available on the internet trying to generate Javadoc in the latest versions of Android Studio, everytime I get the same "package does not exist", import errors and finally without generating any documentation this error is thrown "100 errors. "javadoc" finished with exit code 1,

I am on Mac OS

[image]

What I tried so far as per the solutions given,

[Tried everyting mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296210/generate-javadoc-error-android-studio)

[Also tried the solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70953332/android-failed-to-generate-javadoc-with-android-studio-bumblebee)

Things I have followed in the above solutions,

Replaced .R import with .*
Added dependency

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '/Users/Varaprasad/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
```

used in command line arguments -encoding utf-8 -sourcepath /Users/Varaprasad/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33

[image: Generating Java Doc for specific classes]

Also tried with unchecking the option "Include JDK library sources in -sourcepath" & changing scopes too.

From the above solutions, it was clear there was only one thing - to add the jar dependency. I did it absolutely correct, but with no results. Finally it is the same "100 errors. "javadoc" finished with exit code 1, no matter how many times I try.

No documentation is generated. The output folder is empty.

Please see the log file here: [Generating Doc Error Log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I7kHZ8CoPXJOD8xy1qnoEB0tFYKkk0lZ90Bdx398FX0/edit?usp=sharing)

Cannot generate the same with even new projects too with just a simple "MainActivity.java" and an activity_main.xml file.

Also tried, the solutions that were posted - to add tasks in build.gradle which didn't work in my case.

My Project has kotlin data classes, 1 Util class (with utility methods), along with Java classes - as a part of optimization. This doesn't seem to be a problem.

This was as far as I can reach, no where the solutions seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed gradle in my mac, terminal where my project is located. Using,

`$ brew install gradle`

Then I created a task that generates the Javadocs by ignoring the package errors. [@Julian's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71721535/android-studio-fails-to-generate-javadocs-due-to-packages-not-existing) helped me alot...

Then run the task using the below command in terminal,

`gradle generateReleaseJavadoc`

And there I can finally see the docs generated in the destination folder.